# If $p \gt 3$ is a prime, does $p \mid \sum ij$ such that $1 \le i \lt j \lt p$ always hold?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

> If $p \gt 3$ is a prime, does $$p \mid  \sum ij$$ such that $1 \le i \lt j \lt p$ always hold?

I have tested primes less than 100000 and found no counterexample,  I want to know how to prove it if it's true?

Comment: The crucial thing is to "see through" the $\sum$'s, and realize what numbers are in the sum.

Comment: Re Aqua's answer note that if $p$ is an odd prime $> 3$, and $a$ is a multiple of $\frac{p}{6}$, this implies that $p$ divides $6a$.  However, since $p$ is an odd prime $> 3$, then $p$ must be relatively prime to $6$.  Therefore, since $p$ divides $6a$, $p$ divides $a$.

Comment: A similar line of thought, also related to Aqua's answer is that if $p$ divides a number of the form $(2s)$, then since $p$ is relatively prime to $(2)$, $p$ must divide $(s)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints:

- $$(a+b+c+...)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2+...) = 2({ab+ac+bc+...})$$
- $$ 1+2+...+n = {n(n+1)\over 2}$$
- $$ 1^2+2^2+...+n^2 = {?\over 6}$$

Comment: This shows directly that "prime" can be replaced by a much milder condition

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we have
$$(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-(p-1)) \equiv x^{p-1}-1 \pmod{p}$$

the decomposition of the polynomial $x^{p-1}-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\ [x]$

Comment: @Aqua: same thing, different notation, as seen in many sources.